# How to convert DER formatted public key file to PEM form

Tags: unix, encryption, openssl, public-key

I need to use the PEM formatted public key for some purpose, but not finding the command which can convert DER formatted public key to PEM formatted public key.

The command I have used -
**openssl rsa -in user_id_rsa.pub -inform DER -outform PEM -out pubkey.pem**

But i got the below error -

unable to load Private Key
139901900170912:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1337:
139901900170912:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:677:
139901900170912:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1337:
139901900170912:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:388:Type=RSA

My expected output should be in this format-
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
     **KEY CONTENT**
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

Is anyone has try the same?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Also see [openssl rsa - RSA key processing tool](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html) and `-RSAPublicKey_out` option.

Comment: The error message looks like you're giving it the wrong input, or passing your input to the wrong openssl command. Try `openssl x509` instead if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the information jww, I will keep it in mind.
-RSAPublicKey_out will work when the -in is private key not public key.

Comment: Where did the `user_id_rsa.pub` file come from?  Can you provide instructions for how you generated it, so that we can do the same, to help determine what might be going on?

Comment: it was generated using ssh-keygen command. the problem got resolved, thanks